# Turbine instanceURLSuffix not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, turbine

I'm gathering hystrix streams from turbine but the services have the management port enabled on port 5555.

When I set the property in turbine:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery:8761/eureka/

server.port=8989

InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.class

turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=:5555/hystrix.stream
turbine.InstanceMonitor.eventStream.skipLineLogic.enabled=false
turbine.appConfig=service1,service2,gateway
turbine.clusterNameExpression=new String('default')
```

it tries to connect to:

```
http://gateway-ip:10000/:5555/hystrix.stream
```

instead of replacing the port. Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

I suspect there's an incompatibility between the instanceUrlSuffix and the EurekaInstanceDiscovery.

Is there any information I need to put in `metadataMap` for that service in order to make it work?

> Versions are:
>
> Turbine service:
>
> - spring-cloud-starter-parent: Brixton.SR5
> - spring-cloud-starter-turbine: 1.1.6
>
> Eureka service:
>
> - spring-cloud-starter-parent: Brixton.SR5

Answer (score 2):

To make it work I had to add these two properties to the configuration:

```
turbine:
  instanceInsertPort: false
  instanceUrlSuffix: :5555/hystrix.stream
```

`turbine.instanceInsertPort` is what did the trick, composing the final URL from `schema://host+urlSuffix`

Comment: that is good.. I hoped my answer could give u some direction atleast.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me.
Note: Default profile doesn't work for me either, but individual stream works this way.

my service1 is registered to Eureka with -Dserver.port=5151 and -Dmanagement.port=5152 so my hystrix stream is on different port than my service endpoint.

```
turbine.instanceInsertPort=false
turbine.appConfig=service1
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=SERVICE1
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.USER=:5152/hystrix.stream
InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.EurekaInstanceDiscovery.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Turbine can not read 'turbine.instanceUrlSuffix' in application.property or environment, it need other lib to read properties.

Did you dependency lib `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard` or `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius`? If not, try to add it to your pom.xml.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```